# possibilities to call a database from an executable to another location

Tags: .net, database, exe

I want to know if there are multiple possibilities to call a database from a executable which is in another location. The executable is a .Net application.
I know that with help of a webservice is a possibility. But are there more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about remote access to a database, this is a (possibly incomplete) list:

1. Some service on the machine running the database server that passes data back and forth (as you said, a webservice, but it needn't be a web service, but could also be simple TCP or UDP communication. A webservice just adds more comfort). The advantage of this is that you don't expose your database server to the public. You'd still need to secure communication, however, as otherwise through the service anybody could manipulate the database.
2. You could make the database server reachable from the outside world, even over the internet. That means, you open the DB server's ports in your firewall. Anyone who knows the credentials could log into the server. This is neat and handy, the downside is that hackers could get into your database if you choose weak passwords.
3. You could make sure that machines on the same network can access the database and then dial the machine you're running your application on into a VPN. This may not be very comfortable to the user (your application doesn't work if the VPN isn't dialed in), but is also the most secure way of communicating - from a programmer's point of view - comfortably over the internet (meaning: as comfortable as from any other machine on the same network).

It's basically a question of security over comfort.

Comment: Maybe i could have made my question clearer. I send the exe to a client. If the client opens the exe, it must change a field in the database that is located somewhere else.

Comment: Well, yes, your question could have been clearer, but my answer is *still* valid. :-) These are three ways you can accomplish this. You simply have to check the scenario - does the database reside within the client's network? Use 2), but don't open the port to the internet, only within the local network. Does communication have to go over internet? Use any of 1, 2 or 3 depending on how much work you want to do.

Comment: the least ofcourse :P haha just kidding, it must be very safe. That's the main requirement

Comment: Well, I guess 1) is the hardest to secure. The VPN approach is the securest - if you choose the right type of VPN. The real work is to configure and secure the VPN. Approach 2) is pretty easy to set up and choosing strong passwords (or even certificate authentication) for *every* login (it doesn't make sense to add a strong keyword to the account your application will use, but assign "12345" as the password to the server admin's account) will make it secure, too.

Answer (score 0):

A [database connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is supposed to work over a network. The connection string includes something like a server name or IP address as the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As long as there is an accessible network in between, there is no problem calling your database in every way possible.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar sure, there are a million possibilities why it won't work.When I said "network" I meant an accessible, working network.

Answer (score 0):

The web services route is always an interesting one (and that way you could architecture your software in a way such as some or most of your business logic can reside in said service).

It's possible to self-host a service using WebAPI, and that way you don't even need to run the application inside IIS, but as a self-contained application running, for example, as a Windows Service.

Comment: Although true, this is not actually an answer to the question.